in-text citation: multiple section of a book
I am using APA 7th and IEEE.
In in-text citation, how to refer to multiple section of a book.
I mean, i want to say in chapter C1, section S1 and chapter C2, section S2 the author talked about X.
Here C1 is the chapter name and not number.
And S1 is section name and not number.
I am interested in both Narrative format and Parenthetical format.
I could not find the documentation but I assume the Parenthetical format for APA 7th would look something like:

The author discussed the implications of X (Doe, 2020, Chapter C1,
Section S1; Chapter C2, Section S2).

the Parenthetical format for IEEE would look something like:

The author discussed the implications of X [1, Ch. C1, Sec. S1; Ch. C2,
Sec. S2].

Please let me know if this is correct.
